# Уведомление об изменении в классе

Tags: c#, wpf, события, делегаты

Здравствуйте! При создании приложения в WPF у меня возникла одна проблема, а именно: по нажатию клавиши Edit в главном окне MainWindow я хочу менять свойство IsReadOnly всех компонентов в текущей открытой странице (т.e каким-нибудь образом отловить это событие внутри нашего класса наследованного от Page (сама Page отображается внутри )). И отсюда следует сам вопрос: как оповестить один класс (наш Page) о каких-то изменениях в другом классе (наш MainWindow)? Была идея как-то отловить изменение поля которое будет отражать текущее положение кнопки Edit, однако не знаю, как это сделать. Или же хотел бы узнать другой способ как вообще можно обратиться к полю нашего Page внутри MainWindow?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IG7E.png]

Answer (score 0):

Ну вызвать из одного метода метод другого класса можно либо создав объект этого класса, либо объявить такой метод статическим. По-другому вроде никак, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Что ж, не совсем до конца видимо сформулировал вопрос. Допустим у нас есть List<Page> в котором хранятся разные страницы. И в том то и проблема, что к никакому методу класса производного от класса Page я не могу обратиться просто так, так как он смотрит что таких методов в Page не было. Я хотел бы чтобы страницы хранились именно в списке для дальнейшего удобного манипулирования ими.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте подписку на событие об изменении в Page классе.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event

В Вашем случаи это будет в Page

```
public event Action SomethingChanged = delegate{} //можете использовать EventHandler если нужно что-то еще передать в параметрах.
```

и в другом классе при его инициализации вы можете подписаться на это событие

```
myPage.SomethingChanged += MyMehotd();//тут логика для обработки изменений в стороннем классе.
```

Дальше пока не могу ничего порекомендовать, так как вся логика мне не ясна.